# How can I call a method of a variable, which contains in a namespace?

Tags: c++, methods, namespaces

I've this C++ code in `interface.h`:

```
    #include <iostream>
    class A{
    public:
        void foo();
    };
    namespace interface{
        ...
        namespace Sounds{
            A val;
        };
    }
```

I need to call `.foo` method.
I want to do it in `interface.cpp`:

```
#include "interface.h"

void A::foo(){
    std::cout<<1;
}

interface::Sounds::val.foo();
```

But Clion warns me:

```
No type named 'val' in namespace 'interface::Sounds'
```

What should I do?
Edit: public was added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this both of which are shown below.

##### Method 1: Prior C++17

First method is using the `extern` kewyord in the header file for the *declaration* of `val` and then *define* `val` in the source file before using it as shown below:

**interface.h**

```
#pragma once 
#include <iostream>
class A{
    public: //public added here
    void foo();
};
namespace interface{
    
    namespace Sounds{
        //note the extern here . This is a declaration
        extern A val;
    };
}
```

**interface.cpp**

```
#include "interface.h"

void A::foo(){
    std::cout<<1;
}

//definition 
A interface::Sounds::val;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "interface.h"
int main()
{
    //call member function foo to confirm that it works
    interface::Sounds::val.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/H_6v1sL-M)

The output of the above modified program is:

```
1
```

##### Method 2: C++17

You can use `inline` instead of `extern` with C++17 and onwards to define `val` in the header:

**interface.h**

```
#pragma once 
#include <iostream>
class A{
    public: //public added here
    void foo();
};
namespace interface{
    
    namespace Sounds{
        //note the inline used here
        inline A val{};
    };
}
```

**interface.cpp**

```
#include "interface.h"

void A::foo(){
    std::cout<<1;
}

//nothing needed here as we used inline in the header
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "interface.h"
int main()
{
    //call member function foo to confirm that it works
    interface::Sounds::val.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SMYHE8xat)

Answer (score 2):

You may only declare and define types, functions and objects outside function bodies, thus the compiler looks for the type `val` and can't find it. You may call functions without using their returned results only from functions.

```
int main() {
  interface::Sounds::val.foo();
}
```

Above will be almost successfully compiled, for `val` at least. `void A::foo()` is declared private, thus could not be accessed at `val.foo()` unless it is declared public:

```
class A {
 public:
  void foo();
};
```